# Tracking what and how oberservations changed between two dataframes

Tags: r

I have the following data:

```
x <- c("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee")
y <- c(1, 0, 0, 1, 1)
df1 <- data.frame(x,y)
x <- c("aaa", "bbb", "ccc", "ddd", "eee")
y <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 0)
df2 <- data.frame(x,y)
```

Structure:

```
> df1
    x y
1 aaa 1
2 bbb 0
3 ccc 0
4 ddd 1
5 eee 1
> df2
    x y
1 aaa 1
2 bbb 1
3 ccc 1
4 ddd 1
5 eee 0
```

I'd like to track changes between `df1` and `df2`.

If I `anti_join(df2,df1)` I can keep the things that have changed:

```
x   y
eee 0
ccc 1
bbb 1
```

But I want to know WHAT and HOW things changed from `df1` to `df2`. For example:

```
x   y.from  y.to
eee 1       0
ccc 0       1
bbb 0       1
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May be `inner_join(anti_join(df1, df2), anti_join(df2, df1), by='x')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
#merge on column x
df3 <- merge(df1,df2,by="x")

#show the change
df3[ df3[,2] != df3[,3],]
#     x y.x y.y
# 2 bbb   0   1
# 3 ccc   0   1
# 5 eee   1   0
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try

```
index<-(df1$y!=df2$y)
cbind(df1[index,], df2[index,"y"])
```

Comment: This would work assuming `x` column is same in both data.frames.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a similar `data.table` approach

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(df1), x)
df1[df2][y != i.y]
#      x y i.y
# 1: bbb 0   1
# 2: ccc 0   1
# 3: eee 1   0
```

Answer (score 0):

Piggy backing off @zx8754 here is a hacky `dplyr` version using `filter()`:

```
library(dplyr)
df3 <- merge(df1,df2,by="x") %>%
       filter(y.x != x.x)

#     x y.x y.y
# 2 bbb   0   1
# 3 ccc   0   1
# 5 eee   1   0
```

Comment: Complete `dplyr` solution is already given by @akrun as a comment above. `inner_join(anti_join(df1, df2), anti_join(df2, df1), by='x')`